# Как правильно задать интервал в ajax запросе?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Хотел спросить у тех кто знает, как правильно вставить в ajax запрос,
setInterval   в секунд для обновления div#podblock?

Сам ajax запрос:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            
            $( "#ajaxform" ).submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'), 
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
            
                success: function(result){
                        $('#podblock').html(result);
 
                }

            });

      });
 
});
```

Comment: Вы хотите код в `ajax` повторно вызывать?

Comment: не совсем. Нужно обновлять div #podblock ,  с  интервалом в 1000 секунд, в видеоролике такое видел, но как правильно реализовать не знаю.

Comment: Опишите словами что хотите сделать, пока непонятно

Comment: нужно обновлять блок div раз в 1000 секунд.

Comment: Одним и тем же значением? Или значение запрашивать из ajax? Если первое, то непонятно зачем это нужно делать. Если второе, то нужно код ajax повторно вызывать

Comment: Если вы не понимаете о чем речь, пожалуйста не старайтесь как то решить вопрос

Comment: Сказал несколько раз, нужно обновлять с помощью интервала div с id #podblock раз в секунду

Comment: От того что вы повторите одну и ту же фразу несколько раз понятнее не станет. Объясняю: у вас в коде находится обработчик события `submit`, который вызывается у формы, далее вы формируете ajax запрос, беря адрес, метод HTTP, данные из формы и отправляете. В случаи успешного выполнения ajax запроса будет вызвана функция `success`, в которую ответ из сервера вы засунете в элемент `#podblock` (обновите). Вот и непонятно, что вы хотите время от времени повторять через `setInterval`. Мне кажется, что логично повторять сам запрос в ходе которого будет обновлен `#podblock`, если запрос был успешен